# eLogic Learning LMS - Configuring the Multi-Language feature with Azure Cognitive Services

Tags: azure, multilingual, azure-cognitive-services

I am having difficulty configuring eLogic Learning LMS's Multi-Language feature with Azure's Cognitive Services.  The User Manual states that I must enter my account information as follows:

Subscription Key Name

Subscription Key Value

Where do I find this on my Azure Portal?   I can find my "Subscription Name" which is editable and my "Subscription ID" which is fixed, but when I plug in those values into the LMS, the translation service does not work.  Likewise, I have tried plugging in the Text Translator's "Account Name" and "Key 1" but that does not work either.

eLogic Learning support has stated that they don't provide Azure support.

What am I missing?   Any help is greatly appreciated!   TIA!

Paul

Comment: Kudos to eLogic Learning Support for proactively monitoring Stackoverflow and contacting me to walk me through the configuration !

Comment: For others that may be struggling, the answer was "Subscription Key Name = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" and Subscription Key Value = your unique key from the Azure Portal->Resources section.  In addition, you need to make sure you enable the "Language" field on the LMS Admin "Fields" screen and ensure you have purchased Multi-Language and that eLogic has enabled the Languages on their end.

Comment: You can test your Subscription Key Name and Subscription Key Value here to determine if it is working correctly: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html